# How to get first rows where SQL data is ok

Tags: sql, oracle

I need data in red boxes, this is data where `row_number` (it is ordered by `ddate`) is first and at the start t=2 after the first row that = 4 but not same row where t=2 and so on...

There are only 2, 4, 6, 7 in columns t, tt, ttt, tttt

Can someone help?

[image]

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: 11g oracle version

Comment: This question might get better answers if the sample data is posted as text and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only four columns, a brute force approach isn't so bad:

```
with t as (
      select min(ddate) as t_date
      from t
      where t is not null
     ),
     tt as (
      select min(ddate) as tt_date
      from t
      where tt is not null and
            tt.date > (select t_date from t)
     ),
     ttt as (
      select min(ddate) as ttt_date
      from t
      where ttt is not null and
            ttt.date > (select tt_date from tt)
     ),
     tttt as (
      select min(ddate) as tttt_date
      from t
      where tttt is not null and
            tttt.date > (select ttt_date from ttt)
     )
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select t_date from t) or
      t.date = (select tt_date from tt) or
      t.date = (select ttt_date from ttt) or
      t.date = (select tttt_date from tttt) ;
```

Comment: @VasoMiruashvili - what don't you like about this answer?  If it doesn't solve the problem, then please explain why.